# IIS logging changed from server to site is not being picked up

Tags: logging, iis, iis-10

IIS 10
I have made changes to logging in IIS, including changing the logging from server to site, but the changes are not showing in the logs.
Logging is still going to C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC and not separate site folders.

What needs to be done to make the changes get applied?

Have tried restarting app pool and site that wish to see the logging for (there are many other sites), nothing changed.

I can see the logging coming into the default server log, was expecting a new folder for the site.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once a site is created, its logging settings become its own and will not be affected by the changes you later make on server level.

Thus, what you observed is by design and you have to manually edit each site you want to update.

Comment: Thanks @Lex-Li 
I changed IIS to site level logging, then made changes to the site. I expected the changes I made to the site to be applied.
Is that not how it works?

Comment: @PeteSmith Since day 1 (Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008) it works the way I said, because behind the scenes your server level changes go to `<siteDefaults/logFile>` while a site has its own `<site/logFile>`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/logfile/ Those two sections are not linked.